# How to force Nmap to use -PE option on local network?

Tags: nmap

I am trying to use Host Discovery Nmap function using the `-PE` (ICMP Echo Ping) option to discover hosts on my local network (virtuals machines on bridged connection).

So when I run :

```
nmap -PE 192.168.0.0/24
```

I expect Nmap to send ICMP Echo Ping, but Nmap only send classic TCP request :

[image]

---

Indeed, I have found in the [documentation](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) :

> Also
>   note that ARP/Neighbor Discovery (-PR) is done by default against
>   targets on a local ethernet network even if you specify other -P*
>   options, because it is almost always faster and more effective.

---

But I really need to test the host discovery using ICMP Echo Request (`-PE` option).

How can I force Nmap to do a ICMP Echo Request discovery even if I am on a local ethernet network ? Or is there another workaround to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to disable arp-ping:

```
nmap -sP -PE --disable-arp-ping 192.168.56.1
```

[image]

Comment: Strangely the result is the same... I tried with `--disable-arp-ping` and `--send-ip` as described in the documentation but I still get TCP request. I am missing something here...

Comment: Ooooh got it! I needed to use the command as root.... Thanks !

Comment: @hg8 Also notice use of `-sP` (an alias for `-sn`) to skip the port scan phase, only running host discovery (a.k.a. "ping"). All the TCP packets shown in your Wireshark capture are port scan packets, not host discovery.

Comment: Indeed, I have mixed things. Thanks for the clarification.